# what is appropriate for me? generateAllGrams() or is generateCollocations() enough for me?

Tags: mahout, summarization

I am developing a project on wordnet-based document summarizer.in that i need to extract collocations. i tried to research as much as I could, but since i have not worked with Mahout before I am having difficulty in understanding how CollocDriver.java works (in API context)

while scouring through the web, i landed on this :
 [Mahout Collocations](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Collocations)

this is the problem: i have a POSTagged input text. i need to identify collocations in it.i have got collocdriver.java code..now i need to know how do i use it? whether to use generateAllGrams() method or only generateCollocations() method is enough for my subtask within my summarizer..??

and most importantly HOW to use it? i raise this question coz I admit, i dont know the API well,

i also got a  [grepcode version of collocdriver](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-utils/0.3/org/apache/mahout/utils/nlp/collocations/llr/CollocDriver.java)  the two implementations seem to be slightly different..the inputs are in string for the grepcode version and in the form of Path object in the original...

my questions: what is configuration object in input params and how to use it?? will the source / destn will be in string (as in grepcode) or Path (as in original)??
what will be the output?

i have done some further R & D on collocdriver program...i found out that it uses a sequence file and then vector generation...i wanna know how this sequence file / vector generation works..plz help..

Answer (score 0):

To get collocation using mahout,u need to follow some simple steps

1) You must make a sequence file from ur input text file.

/bin/mahout seqdirectory -i  /home/developer/Desktop/colloc/ -o /home/developer/Desktop/colloc/test-seqdir -c UTF-8 -chunk 5

2)There are two ways to generate collocations from a sequence file.

```
a)Convert sequence file to sparse vector and find out the collocation
b)Directly find out the collocation from the sequence file (with out creating the sparse vector)
```

3)Here i am considering choice b.

/bin/mahout org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.collocations.llr.CollocDriver -i /home/developer/Desktop/colloc/test-seqdir  -o /home/developer/Desktop/colloc/test-colloc -a org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DefaultAnalyzer -ng 3 -p

Just check out the output folder,the files u need is over there !!! (in sequence file format)

/bin/mahout seqdumper -s /home/developer/Desktop/colloc/test-colloc/ngrams/part-r-00000 >> out.txt will give u a text output !!!